# Problema ao enviar strings com caracteres especiais em xmlrpc

Tags: python, python-2.7

Venho a algum tempo recebendo o erro:

```
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault -32700: 'parse error. not well formed'>
```

Ao tentar enviar a seguinte string via **xmlrpc**, No **python 2.7**

```
    base = 'áaaáá´´oeéé'
```

Xmlrpc não é capaz de enviar este tipo de carácter? como posso corrigir?